# unique API key in php

Tags: php, cakephp, phpmyadmin

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit']) and $_GET['action'] == "Add")
{
    $Users->copyPostData();
    $Users->_password(md5($_POST[password]));
    $Users->_status(0);
    $Users->_apikey(md5("ONE@:".$_POST[uname].":@STEP"));

    $userNum = $Users->checkUserExist($Users->_username());
    $userEmail = $Users->checkEmailExist($Users->_email());
    if(($userNum == '0' || $userNum == '') && ($userEmail == '0' || $userEmail == '')) {

    $randomVar = generateRandomNo(8);
    $Users->_activationcode($randomVar);
```

my this line of code generate an API KEY and saves it in my database. my table name is USERS.. but the api key that this line of code generates is same for the all users... 
 i want the unique API key for all the users... can u please help?

```
$Users->_apikey(md5("ONE@:".$_POST[uname].":@STEP"));
```

Comment: Does `$_POST['uname']` contain anything that's unique?

Comment: I guess `$_POST[uname]` will be different each time, so how can it generate same key each time. You should try first with `$_POST['uname']` instead `$_POST[uname]`. It seems that you missed the quotes

Comment: i  had added quotes but no difference

Comment: Try submitting form with two different usernames and still keys will same, than your code may have some other problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the md5 of a string and the only reason its the same for all users is because the string is same for everyone.

check the content of `$_POST['uname']`

Comment: i  had added quotes but no difference

Answer (score 2):

You should use uniqid() to generate the unique key! it is a built-in php function by the way.